# Python dash - weird whitespace to right of Navbar

Tags: python, css

I am using a simple Navbar in my Python dash app, which I call as follows:

```
app.layout = html.Div(children=[

    navbar.Navbar,

    dbc.Row(dbc.Col(
        [html.H3('Global Indicators')],
        style={'text-align': 'center', 'padding-top': '4vh','padding-right': '0pt'}
    )),
    
]
```

The code for the Navbar is as follows:

```
Navbar = dbc.NavbarSimple(
    children=[
        dbc.NavItem(dbc.NavLink("Economy", href="#")),
        dbc.NavItem(dbc.NavLink("Global", href="#")),
    ],
    brand="Analytics for Covid-19 Policy",
    brand_href="/app",
    color="primary",
    sticky="top",
    dark = True,
)
```

For some reason, this results in whitespace, **but only to the right of the Navbar**:

[image]

Any idea why this is happening and how to fix it?